# How can i redirect to another page when user edit information and then press save button in magento

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I want to add redirection when user edit information and then press the save button. In my scenario, this is my setting controller code

```
 $data = array(
                    "user_id" => ((isset($user)) ? $user->getId() : ""),
                    "shipping_address" => $Params['shipping_address'],
                    "phone_number" => $Params['phone'],
                    "add_datetime" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                    "update_datetime" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            );


unset($data['celebrity_user_id']);
            unset($data['celebrity_add_datetime']);
            $model = $celebModel->load($Params['id'])->addData($data);
            $model->setId($Params['id'])->save();
            $model2 = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($Params['user_id']);

            $data['success'] = "Celebrity update successfully";

            $this->loadLayout();

        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('setting');
            if ($block) {
                $block->setData($data);
            }

        $this->renderLayout();
```

So, when user update information in setting page and click on Save Button (Here is view),

```
<button type="reset" class="info">CANCEL</button>
<button type="submit" class="info"><?php echo (isset($data['post']['id']) ? "SAVE" : "SAVE"); ?></button>
```

Then it should redirect to my Dashboard page. Is it any idea how to add redirection in magento. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use window.location in javascript after submission in database.

Comment: Please check $this->_redirect(); function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the controller action

```
<?php $this->_redirect('adminhtml/dashboard') ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check that the info was saved and use that Boolean value to determine if you should redirect to the dashboard page.

```
if ($infoSaved) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/dashboard');
        exit;
        } else {
        /* Inform the user something went wrong */
        }
```

Comment: magento provides so many in build methods for redirection, using header location with exit does not seem to be a good option.

Comment: Blastfreak, your absolutely right. My solution wasn't optimal. I should have thought for a moment before posting. Thanks.